# ERROR: invalid string in message when querying into a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, postgresql-9.5

I have this query:

```
SELECT "user".id AS user_id,
   "user".is_verified AS user_is_verified, 
   "user".name AS user_name, 
   "user".nickname AS user_nickname, 
   "user".password AS user_password, 
   "user".birthdate AS user_birthdate, 
   "user".food_restrictions AS user_food_restrictions, 
   "user".email AS user_email, 
   "user".telephone AS user_telephone, 
   "user".address AS user_address, 
   "user".shirt_size AS user_shirt_size, 
   "user".type AS user_type, 
   "user".created_at AS user_created_at, 
   "user".updated_at AS user_updated_at, 
   "user".image AS user_image, 
   "user".is_image_url AS user_is_image_url, 
   "user".code AS user_code, 
   "user".terms_accepted AS user_terms_accepted, 
   "user".recive_mails AS user_recive_mails, 
   "user".lleidacoins_claimed AS user_lleidacoins_claimed, 
   "user".token AS user_token, 
   "user".refresh_token AS user_refresh_token, 
   "user".verification_token AS user_verification_token, 
   "user".rest_password_token AS user_rest_password_token, 
   hacker.user_id AS hacker_user_id, 
   hacker.banned AS hacker_banned, 
   hacker.github AS hacker_github, 
   hacker.linkedin AS hacker_linkedin, 
   hacker.cv AS hacker_cv, 
   hacker.studies AS hacker_studies, 
   hacker.study_center AS hacker_study_center, 
   hacker.location AS hacker_location, 
   hacker.how_did_you_meet_us AS hacker_how_did_you_meet_us
FROM hacker_event_accepted, 
     "user" JOIN hacker ON "user".id = hacker.user_id
WHERE 1 = hacker_event_accepted.event_id 
      AND hacker.user_id = hacker_event_accepted.user_id
```

psql shows this error:

> ERROR:  invalid string in message

I was trying this in a fastapi but also trying the query directly on a psql connection fails either, I have searched and postgresql has a max query limit but is 1600 columns and also if I remove 4 columns from the select the query works perfectly

Comment: I tried to rename the table from user to my_user and the query also fails

Comment: The `invalid string in message` only occurs in PostgreSQL as a protocol error. That suggests you have a problem in your database driver or something like that.

Comment: I don't think so as any other operation works perfectly

Comment: Could there be some data corruption? Do the four columns you mentioned cause any problems by themselves? The error message is to do with an unexpected string length.

Comment: You can remove any of 4 column selects and it works, i also tryed to remove all the data from the tables and added again and the data isn't corrupted, also if you want i can send you the backend that generates this problem 

[link](https://github.com/LleidaHack/LleidaHackBackend/tree/refactor)

you can try the get all accepted hackers endpoint
@RichardHuxton

Comment: Well - if you want to figure out how you are triggering this error, it's only occurrence in the source that I can find is in `pqformat.c` in `pq_getmsgstring` and `pq_getmsgrawstring` (v15 but unlikely to have changed over the versions much).